# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while passing array to new ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, exc-bad-access

I'm loading some XML from a webservice (car data), create some car objects and would like to display them in a TableViewController.

When the user has selected start and destination location, I'm making an async call to the webservice, show an activity indicator and as soon as the data is loaded, I go to a new view. So I have something like this:

```
 class NewReservationViewController : UIViewController {
       @IBAction func searchCarsClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            //show load cars activity indicator
            loadingCarsActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

            //load available cars from webservice asyncronously
           DataManager.getAvailableCars([...parameter list...], carsLoadedCallback: carsLoaded)


        }

        func carsLoaded(loadedCars: [Car]) {
            //dismiss the waiting widget
            //trigger the segue and advance to the next screen

            loadingCarsActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            print("stopped cars loading activity indicator")
            print("cars loaded callback called")
            print("loaded \(loadedCars.count) distinct cars")

            self.cars = loadedCars
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showAvailableCars", sender: self)

        }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showAvailableCars" {

            let carTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CarTableViewController
            carTableViewController.cars = self.cars
            presentViewController(carTableViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}






class DataManager {


   class func getAvailableCars([...parameter list...], carsLoadedCallback: ([Car]) -> Void){
       Webservice.getAvailability([...parameter list...], completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in


           //parse xml
           //in the end I get an Array of Car objects


           var cars: [Car] = ...

           carsLoadedCallback(cars)

        })}
   }
}
```

When I populate the TableView with some DummyData I create within the CarTableViewController class, it works fine. However when I try to pass the car arrays to my TableViewController I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2 exception. As far as I know this is some kind of Memory exception that is usually caused by a corrupt pointer. So I guess that the car array I created in my static DataManager class within the static method I called gets destroyed. However I'm not sure about that because automatic reference counting should avoid that.

The table view even displays the data but then immediately crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. I tried to set a general breakpoint in the XCode's breakpoints tab but however I don't get a reasonable error message on why the app crashes.

Do you have any ideas on why this happens. How can I get a better error message?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check this function:

```
func carsLoaded(loadedCars: [Car])
```

It is returned as callback - what thread is it running? main or backround?
You should call on main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  performSegueWithIdentifier("showAvailableCars", sender: self)
})
```

If doesn't help - provide the line, where it breaks in debugger, so I can help and see more.

UPD: Didn't notice, why do you do manual present?

```
presentViewController(carTableViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Your segue automatically shows view controller, you can change it's style (modal, push) in storyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately the app still crashes when I do this. My problem is that I don't get a reasonable error message. I simply see the AppDelegate and a red error message with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. So I don't see where it breaks in the debugger.

Comment: Set breakpoint to these lines: `loadingCarsActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()`, `self.cars = loadedCars`, `performSegueWithIdentifier("showAvailableCars", sender: self)`, `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`. Where does it stop? where not?

Comment: It stops on every breakpoint. However I noticed something weird. If I try to stop the activity indicator on the main thread using dispatch_async, it goes on anyway even after the statement has been executed.

Comment: what is this? ` presentViewController(carTableViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)` remove this line. Your segue shows a view controller and you do it manually one more time.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential issues that I can see. The first is that you are triggering your segue from a method that might not be on the main thread, you need to ensure that this is done on the main thread. The other issue is that in your prepare for segue you are unwrapping the new ViewController without checking it, so try this instead:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showAvailableCars" {

        if let carTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? CarTableViewController {
            carTableViewController.cars = self.cars
            presentViewController(carTableViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I definetely should use if let in this case. The app still crashes. However if I do the Webservice call on my main thread wouldn't the app freeze? Then it would be a synchronous call. What do you think about my general approach? Is there a cleaner and less error-prone solution where I don't run into threading problems?

Comment: You don't need to do the API call on the main thread, you need to call performSegue on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

As you said the table view displays the data and then immediately crashes I would assume that the problem is in your CarTableViewController. One thing you could check is when your cells are rendered, if you are trying to access some information that is null from the Car objects